# Storing temporary values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have to store value for temporary use so I used `SharedPrefences` for that but in this case when the user goes to <kbd>Setting</kbd> -> <kbd>Application</kbd> -> <kbd>Application</kbd> and then clicks on <kbd>Force stop</kbd> and <kbd>Clear data</kbd> then `SharedPrefences` is lost. So is there any suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a good reason to guard against the case of the user clearing your data?

Comment: yeah actually I have to display message according to the user views so I wanna do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only work around to fix this problem is to use a web service and store your data on the server. You can make device IMEI as primary key to avoid duplication.

Comment: yeah thanks I thought this also but is there any option on client side

Comment: you said right,,,i googled lot and there is no option else thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use element [`android:manageSpaceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#space) in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to point to an activity. So when the user goes to the details page of your app in Settings, there will be a button <kbd>Manage space</kbd> instead of <kbd>Clear data</kbd>. Clicking that button will bring your specified activity up. Then you can show the user options to manage data (database, preferences…).

Comment: nice to know this good this but it's not full fill my requirement

Comment: is this android:manageSpaceActivity must be given for each activity

Comment: @saran No, just the one you want to show it to the user. I think it is unique.

Answer (score 0):

as already mentioned above, the only proper way to prevent the user from having the possibility to delete your app data is storing the data on the web and download when needed. You can do both and then perform a check on runtime. If the required data is missing, then it gets downloaded